# cordova-plugin-buildinfo does not get correct data only on android .AAB

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

## **Environment**

Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon
Linux Kernel 5.15.0-84-generic

cordova 11.1.0
cordova-android 11.0.0
cordova-ios 6.2
node 16.19.0

Java JDK: 11.0.20
Gradle: 8.1.1
Android target: android-33,android-32,android-31,android-30,android-29

## **Problem**

After i update my app to use cordova 11.1 (before it was 10), cordova-android 11 (before it was 9) to target android 33 (before it was 30), when i tried to get the data of BuildInfo on javascript, the plugin return all data as null, empty strings or zero value. This happens only when i build the app with `cordova build --release android --buildConfig` , because when i use `cordova build --debug android --buildConfig` it works fine. The only difference of these commands is "--debug" generate an ".apk" and "--release" generates an ".aab".
This happens only on android, ios works fine.

I suppose that some of the updates change something that broke the plugin.

I tried to regenerate the android folder.

Comment: Seems like a plugin issue, you'd rather open an issue on github than here...

Answer (score 0):

I am using another plugin named cordova-plugin-proguard. I had to create a **'proguard-custom.txt'** file with the following configuration:

```
-keep public class **.BuildConfig { *; }
```

As far as I understand, this configuration tells Proguard not to obfuscate the class that cordova-plugin-buildinfo uses to capture the data.

I followed the instructions provided by the repository owner after they responded to my issue. Link to my issue response: https://github.com/lynrin/cordova-plugin-buildinfo/issues/24